# How to mock Time without a testing library in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to mock Time.now in the console to return a given time, say 30 minutes from now. This is on a staging server that does not have RSpec available.

The following did not work because it creates a loop and raises SystemStackError:

```
t = Time.now + 30.minutes
t.to_s 
=> "2014-02-28T17:33:37Z"

class Time
  def self.now
    iso8601 "2014-02-28T17:33:37Z"
  end
end

Time.now
```

Working in Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting time to an integer works for me:

```
class Time
  def self.now
    Time.at(1393610063)
  end
end

Time.now
#=> 2014-02-28 09:54:23 -0800

sleep 5

Time.now
#=> 2014-02-28 09:54:23 -0800
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) was designed for this exact purpose. Though it was designed to make testing easy, it's not a "testing framework" -- it does not require rspec or rails and can be used in any ruby project.

The `freeze` method allows you to *statically* mock the current time:

```
# Assume it is currently 12:00:00 on 3/1/2015
Timecop.freeze( Time.now + 30.minutes ) do
  puts Time.now                      # --> shows 12:30:00
  do_something_for_fifteen_seconds
  puts Time.now                      # --> still shows 12:30:00; time has not passed
end
```

The `travel` method allows you to *dynamically* mock the current time:

```
Timecop.travel( Time.now + 30.minutes ) do
  puts Time.now                      # --> shows 12:30:00
  do_something_for_fifteen_seconds
  puts Time.now                      # --> shows 12:30:15; time has passed but we are still 30 minutes ahead of reality
end
```

And the `scale` method allows you to mock the passage of time faster (or slower) than reality:

```
Timecop.scale( 60 ) do
  puts Time.now                      # --> shows 12:00:00
  do_something_for_fifteen_seconds
  puts Time.now                      # --> shows 12:15:00; time has passed 60 times faster,
                                     # so 15 seconds of real time appears as 15 minutes
end
```

The gem's website has more information and examples.